# Asymmetric Key import from cert erroring

Tags: marketing-cloud, key

Received a public key generated in a .crt format from Commerce Cloud side so that we can pass an encrypted emailaddr through an email click for attribution.

However, getting this error: `The key file does not contain any valid public encryption keys.`

Is there some kind of decryption needed?  I am able to add in the SFMC provided public key example from documentation - so I know it's not a specific issue with the upload functionality.